# Align radio buttons inside radio group

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an Android 3.1 Tablet application and asking this here because I haven't found any working answer (or example) in my code.

I have the following piece of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/materialsLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
                                                <!-- 0 . Título del fragment -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/layout_title_quantity"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
                                                <!-- 1. Texto -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/layout_qty_size_carton"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                                                <!-- 2. Texto -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum=".45" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/layout_req_po"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".05"
                android:text="@string/layout_qty_carton"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/qtyPerCartonTxt"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".05"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".01"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/layout_slash"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".05"
                android:text="@string/layout_cartoon_size"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cartonSizeTxt"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".05"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".01"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/layout_slash"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".03"
                android:text="@string/layout_weight"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cartonWeightTxt"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".05"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
                                                <!-- 3. Titulo tabla -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/layout_actual_finding"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                                                <!-- 4. Cabecera tabla -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum=".5" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".07"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/layout_cartoon_number"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".07"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/layout_actual_qty"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".07"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/layout_actual_size"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".07"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/layout_actual_weight"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAddNewActPckCtr"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".05"
                android:onClick="onAddNewActPckCtrClick"
                android:text="@string/btn_add_new" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum=".5" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".07"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/layout_result"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rGroupResQTYOnline"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight=".07"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >


                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rResQTYOnlineYes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/layout_yes" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rResQTYOnlineNo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/layout_no" />

            </RadioGroup>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rGroupResSzOnline"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".07"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rResSzOnlineYes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/layout_yes" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rResSzOnlineNo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/layout_no" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rGroupResWgOnline"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".07"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rResWgOnlineYes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/layout_yes" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rResWgOnlineNo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/layout_no" />
            </RadioGroup>



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTakeQtyOnlinePhoto"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".07"
            android:onClick="onTakePhotoClick"
            android:text="@string/btn_take_photo" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/layout_photos"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/quantityOnlineGallery"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dip" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I'm trying to center radio buttons inside radiogroup but I don't know how to do it.

I have tried this code:

```
 <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
   <RadioButton
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:layout_gravity="center|left"/>
   <RadioButton
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center|right" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

But it doesn't work.

**How can I do it?**

Comment: Post your full xml code.

Comment: Question updated with full xml code.

Comment: how you actually want ? can you show image

Comment: look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464171/how-to-align-radio-button-at-the-center-of-the-screen/17607367#17607367

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It might help to try this:
Align your radio group to center

```
<RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/rGroupResSzOnline"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".07"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rResSzOnlineYes"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Yes" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/rResSzOnlineNo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="No" />
            </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: android:gravity="center" is the key

Comment: What if i want one radio button on left side, other on right side and another at top...??

Answer (score 0):

Since RadioGroup overrides linearlayout, you can align the radiobutton similar to child views of linear layout.

1. if you want to align all child radiobuttons to centre: `<RadioGroup.... android:gravity="centre" ...>`
2. if you want one radio button at start another at end:
   `<RadioButton1... android:layout_weight="1".../>`
   `<RadioButton2... android:layout_weight="1".../>` 
   it will assign equal space to both RadioButtons if you want to force align RadioButton2 to extreme end, just do not assign layout_weight to it.

Answer (score -5):

Have you tried to nest a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout inside the RadioGroup and put the  RadioButton within it? I haven't tried myself so I don't know if it works.

Comment: If you do like this, RadioGroup will not work, because RadioButtons must be direct children of RadioGroup;