# How to align radio button to center

Tags: android, radio-button, layout-gravity

I want radio buttons in the image below to be `center` aligned. I have used gravity but it's not working.

[image]
I have used this code

```
   <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/qualityRadioGroup"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="5"
                    >


                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/qty1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:button="@drawable/radio_button_selector"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:tag="1"/>


                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/qty2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="@dimen/s5dp"
                        android:button="@drawable/radio_button_selector"
                        android:tag="2"
                        />


                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/qty3"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="@dimen/s5dp"
                        android:button="@drawable/radio_button_selector"
                        android:tag="3"
                        />


                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/qty4"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="@dimen/s5dp"
                        android:button="@drawable/radio_button_selector"
                        android:tag="4"
                        />


                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/qty5"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="@dimen/s5dp"
                        android:button="@drawable/radio_button_selector"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:tag="5"/>


                </RadioGroup>
```

If i add radio buttons inside linear layout than it gets aligned to center but radio group functionality does not work in that situation.

I want center aligned radio buttons along with radio group feature i.e only one item should be selected at a time.

Comment: which layout are u using linear or relative

Comment: this will help, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464171/how-to-align-radio-button-at-the-center-of-the-screen

Comment: @Don'tBenegative - its  inside Linear layout

Comment: try with relative layout gravity etc works on relative only

Comment: @Don'tBenegative-Relative layout is also generating same result.

Answer (score 12):

I have a workaround for this issue

```
    android:textSize="0.1sp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/selector_dashboard_button"
    android:button="@null"
```

Added these things instead of  android:background=""

Here is my full layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:button="@null"
    android:checked="true"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/selector_dashboard_button"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:tag="1"
    android:textSize="0.1sp" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/selector_inventory_button"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="0.1sp" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/selector_check_list_button"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="0.1sp" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/selector_vendor_button"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="0.1sp" />
</RadioGroup>
```

**Here is the screenshot of my code**
[image]

Comment: Outstanding. Wonderful solution.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but I just found a solution that works fine for my case:

Add `android:minWidth="0dp"` to your radioButton, that should remove the spaces to the left and right side of the button drawable.

Works great if you have a LinearLayout with a TextView and want the button to be centered perfectly horizontally above or below the TextView.

Answer (score 2):

Try this i have tested
Add FrameLayout and give child weight into this and remove weight from Radiobutton and give center layout gravity to Radiobutton it will give as you want

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/qualityRadioGroup"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/qty1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:button="@null"

            android:tag="1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/qty2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:button="@null"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:tag="2" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/qty3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:button="@null"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:tag="3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/qty4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:button="@null"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:tag="4" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/qty5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:button="@null"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:tag="5" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

And For Drawable Selector Please Refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12432722/1311951)

[image: Sample Layout Screen]

Comment: in that case RadioGroup functionality does not works ie. we are able to select all radio buttons

Comment: not getting can you please give me a reason for this  why its not working

Comment: It will get center aligned but it will allow multi select radio button whareas i want single select radio button functionality

Comment: @Ragini The Radio button is used to select only once from Radio group.
If you want to select multiple selection you have to integrate checkbox

Comment: @EthicsDev- I want single select.But if i am adding radio buttons inside frame layout than it allows multi-select, which i don't want

Comment: @Ragini sorry i got your point use same your layout just put the background and put button="@null" and in background put drawable selector

Comment: Let me know if you need any help @Ragini

Comment: In that case  drawable scaled to fit entire weight

Comment: @Ragini you can fix height and weight with drawable Go this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163628/adding-custom-radio-buttons-in-android

Comment: Good but you set all center with background after removing weight. Kindly accept answer or comment

Comment: <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/qty1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:button="@null"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/radio_button_selector"
                        android:tag="1"/>

Comment: @EthicsDev- I have    used android:button="@null" & 
android:drawableTop="@drawable/radio_button_selector" & not used background

Answer (score 1):

Below mentioned code is working.

```
 <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/qty1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:button="@null"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/radio_button_selector"
                        android:tag="1"/>
```

Add
 android:button="@null"
                         android:drawableTop="@drawable/radio_button_selector"

Answer (score 0):

use margins to put the circle in middle

```
<RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/qty4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/s5dp"
                    android:button="@drawable/radio_button_selector"
                    android:tag="4"
                    android:marginLeft="5dp" 
                    />
```

for different screens you need to do it Programmatically 
and read this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464171/how-to-align-radio-button-at-the-center-of-the-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add gravity = "center" inside radio group and  check

```
<LinearLayout                        
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <RadioGroup
                  android:id="@+id/qualityRadioGroup"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"                  
                  android:weightSum="5">
                 <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/qty1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:button="@drawable/radio_button_selector"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:tag="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Ragini what layout you are using

Comment: Its inside linear layout

Comment: @Ragini check the updated answer try to add a linear layout before the radio group and add gravity for the linear layout.

Comment: in that case RadioGroup functionality does not works ie. we are able to select all radio buttons

Comment: @Ragini then try to give radio button set checked as false in xml

Comment: @Ragini give checked false for all radio buttons in xml

Answer (score 0):

Can you try providing the same layou width for both the text and the radiobutton & give them the gravity `Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL` ?

Thanks

Comment: Text and radiobutton both has  android:layout_weight="1"

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `Linearlayout` to `Relativelayout`

Because gravity may not work on Linear layout

Answer (score 0):

use margins & remove weight to put the circle in middle

```
 <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/qty1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:tag="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Remove all padding from the RadioButtons
- Add a LinearLayout either side of each RadioButton
- Set the dimensions of the LinearLayouts to your desired margin sizes
- Set onClickListeners for these LinearLayouts

**In your layout:**

```
             <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btn2_padding_left"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_btn_pg2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:duplicateParentState="true"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                android:scaleX="0.5"
                android:scaleY="0.5" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btn2_padding_right"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

**In your activity class:**

```
    btn2_padding_left.setOnClickListener {
        radio_btn_pg2.isChecked = true
    }
    btn2_padding_right.setOnClickListener {
        radio_btn_pg2.isChecked = true
    }
```